# How to easily isolate parts of a shape to fill them with colour in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, fill

I am using Adobe Illustrator and I have a ribbon shape that I have created using the pen tool and line segments.

I need to know how to isolate areas so I can fill them with a colour and create the illusion that the back and front of the ribbon curves through my layout.

**How can I isolate parts of the shape I've created to add or change colours?**

Comment: do you have  any screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

You can split your general shape into several parts to apply different fills:

1) make the desired number of copies by pasting them directly in front of the original shape: copy with **Ctrl+C** ---> paste to front by **Ctrl+F** 

2) then draw a *subtracting shape* over one of that copies, make them both selected (but not any of the other copies below!), and use the **Pathfinder** panel - find a button "Minus front"

Thus you should get the desired parts of the original shape to fill them with different colors/gradients/patterns to achieve the realistic image of ribbon :)

Answer (score 0):

Select all.

Grab the **Live Paint Bucket Tool**

Click once to create Live Paint Group

Pick a swatch color

click where you want that color.

When everything is colored, click the `Expand` button in the control bar across the top of the screen.